# How do you override a translation for a specific module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, localisation

I need to change the text on an item in a 3rd party extension from "Apply" to "Redeem".  Since Apply is used in other modules as well I want to make sure to only affect instance of "apply" in the module specifically.

In Magento 1 this could be done using the line below in the theme's translation file...

`"Module_Name::Apply","Redeem"`

I tried this in Magento 2 and it does not seem to work and I didn't see any mention of an alternative in the [Magento Translate Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html). Is there a way to accomplish this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"Apply", "Redeem", module, Module_Name`

Example in [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html#element-translations-per-module)

> "Add to Cart", "Add to Cart", module, Magento_Review
>
> "Add to Cart", "Add to Shopping Cart", module, Magento_Catalog

Comment: This saved me ! Thx !

Comment: Are you sure this works? I could not get this to work. It always seems to translate with the last translation row on the language package's translation file.

Comment: Do not forget to execute below command.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

I spent a day to make above code working with the help of this command.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by **`creating`** an independent **language translation** file inside your **`3rd party extension (custom module)`**.

First **`create`** **`i18n`** directory inside your **`custom module`**
Then **`create`** a **language file** and name it **`en_US.csv`**
Inside that language file put your translation

```
Apply, Redeem
```

Save it then run **`cache:flush`**

It should **translate** only the specific **'apply'** from your **`custom module`** and will not affect any other module using the **'apply'** instance

check if it works!

Comment: I am having the same issue. While this method works, since the extension is 3rd party, translations get deleted whenever the extension is updated.